# How to access the object inside the private method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have mocked the private method using the PowerMock/Mockito , now my question here is how can I access the object declared inside this method ?

for example .

```
private void method1()
{
MyObject ob = new MyObject();

}
```

now in my test code I want to access the ob object to verify the values .

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember seeing a way to mock the constructor call somehow, and make it return a mock object, that can be inspected afterwards

Comment: You may provide some precisions of what you are trying to accomplish. Because it seems to me that you are not using the right approach if you want to check internal fields of a private method.

Comment: @ppeterka: I don't want to modify the code

Comment: @user2181531 you don't want to modify the **test** code? Your original code you want to test does not have to be modified by what I proposed...

Comment: @ppeterka: you said make a return mock object, where I assumed the code which needs to be tested should be modified. And mine is not a constructor.lets take example Class A { private void method1() { Obj obj = new Obj(); obj.setX(10);} Here I want to access the obj object to verify the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) details mocking a constructor call using PowerMock:

> ... 
>   But with PowerMock you don't have to change the code, instead you can instruct PowerMock to intercept the call to new File(..) and return a mock object instead. To do this we start by creating a mock of type File.class as usual:
>
> ```
> File fileMock = createMock(File.class);
> ```
>
> To expect the call to new File we simply do:
>
> ```
> expectNew(File.class, "directoryPath").andReturn(fileMock);
> ```

So in your case, you should have these in your **test case or setup method**:

```
MyObject mockOb = createMock(MyObject.class);
expectNew(MyObject.class).andReturn(mockOb);
```

By adding these, you will have the following behaviour:

Whenever there is a `new MyObject()` in **your code** run by the test case, the object instance mocked by PowerMock will be returned. So it does not matter *where* in your code you create a new `MyObject` instance, it will be the very same one created by the `createMock()` function.

**EDIT**

> lets take example
>
> ```
> Class A { 
>  private void method1() 
>  { 
>    Obj obj = new Obj(); 
>     obj.setX(10);
>  } 
>  //Here I want to access the obj object to verify the values 
> }
> ```

To accomplish this, you have to think a bit differently.

1. create real A instance
2. set up mocking for the Obj constructor
3. run your logic that triggers the `pruivate method1()`
4. check the values *on the mocked Obj instance*

   - if the values are not testable (something modifies it in the logic), zou could check if the setX() was called the appropriate times.

Something along these lines:

```
@Test
public void testMyPrivateMethod() {
    //1. object with the logic to test
    A a = new A();

    //2. set up mocking
    Obj mockObj = createMock(Obj.class);
    expectNew(Obj.class).andReturn(mockObj);

    //3. trigger logic to test
    a.someOtherMethodThatCallsMethod1();

    //4. test Obj (find out if setX() has been called or not)
    verify(mockObj).setX(any(Integer.class));
}
```

Comment: My method does not return the same object as you create when mocking

Comment: lets take example Class A { private void method1() { Obj obj = new Obj(); obj.setX(10);} Here I want to access the obj object to verify the values

Comment: The return type of your method is `void`. It doesn't return anything. I don't understand what you write... Do you understand how mocking works?

Comment: That is what I am trying to tell , I know and I am able to mock the method , and I am able to get into the method , the only thing is this object is getting saved in the database and at test level I dont have my db up and I dont want to make it up , so I want to access this object which is sitting inside the private method

Comment: your edited things looks like on the track answer to me...let me see If I can follow it

Comment: but for this I need to mock the default constructor of the Obj.

Comment: @user2181531 I added some code, but I can't test it now (no Powermock around at the time). But it should be at least partly correct. Also, `expectNew(Obj.class).andReturn(mockObj)` mocks the default constructor (no arguments) of the Obj class. All the code that is run by your test class will have the mockObj instance when they run a `new Obj()` anywhere.

Comment: Just want to make sure is it PowerMock/Mockito compatible ?

Comment: @user2181531 The expectNew is PowerMock, what I'm not 100% sure is the verify - but I think it comes from easymock, so should work...